# Kommasetzung in Objektivsätzen

Tags: comma, subordinate-clause

> Wie viele Socken Sie in den Koffer packen, bestimmen Sie selbst.

Für mich fühlt sich das Komma falsch an. Darf es dort stehen?

Comment: Willkommen bei GermanSE, Martin, und schön, dass du gleich mit einer Frage startest! Diese Seite bietet allerdings weder Lektorat noch Ersatz für Nachschlagewerke, weshalb ich dafür stimme, diese Frage zu schließen.

Comment: Ja kann ich verstehen. Ist jetzt auch für einen sehr konkreten Fall und damit nicht wirklich für andere Nutzer von zukünftiger Bedeutung. Kann ich vote-to-close für meine eigene Frage auslösen?

Comment: Du kannst anders fragen: warum muss / darf da ein Komma hin oder warum nicht?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ja. Nach alter Rechtschreibung muss es sogar. Nach der Rechtschreibreform von 1996 muss es nicht mehr, aber es darf.

Comment: Ist es dasselbe, wenn wir die Satzteile tauschen? "_Sie bestimmen selbst(,) wie viele Socken Sie in den Koffer packen_" - muss hier ein Komma stehen?

Comment: Nach der guten alten Rechtschreibung jedenfalls: ja. Nach der neuen: Da kennt sich eh kein Mensch mehr aus.

Comment: @Eller Bezüglich der Komma-setzung wurden mit der Rechtschreibreform an vielen Stellen Kommata optional gemacht, wenn das Weglassen des Kommas den Satz nicht mehrdeutig oder schwer verständlich gemacht hat. Ich würde in diesem Fall das Komma setzen, weil es das Verständnis schon beim Lesen erleichtert. Es wäre wahrscheinlich nicht falsch, das Komma *nicht* zu setzen, aber dann müsste man den Satz ggf. mehrmals lesen, um seine Struktur richtig zu erfassen.

Comment: Es mag nach "neuer Rechtschreibung" theoretisch erlaubt sein, das Komma hier wegzulassen. Wer es aber weglässt, begibt sich in Gefahr,  als jemand angesehen zu werden, der Probleme mit der Kommasetzung hat.