# Comma possible or not?

Tags: comma

I have the following sentence:

> Ich habe angefangen, Medizin zu studieren.

Not having a comma is okay, but is a comma *possible* if somebody insists on adding one?

Does it make a difference if I extend the sentence a bit:

> Ich hab meinen Lebenstraum erfüllt und angefangen, Medizin zu studieren.

Comment: Related in german: [Kommasetzung in Objektivsätzen](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/40398).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but not mandatory: [Rule (German)](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#K116)

Comment: I suggest quoting the appropriate paragraph so your answer stays valid even if the link goes down.

Comment: It should be added that the comma was in fact mandatory until not too long ago. Most adults will know the older rule from their school days.